Demonstration of the inverse additive of an element of Z is unique
Recently I saw on youtube a demonstration of this that used the axioms of $\mathbb{Z}$ but only used the distributibe law https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tiU32g2tYkE (audio is in Spanish). This got me to question why he didn't used the commutative law  which got me pretty quick to a shorter demonstration.
The demonstration is as follows:
Let be $a \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $b, c$ two of it's additive inverses then:
$$
a + b = 0 = a + c \implies a + b + b = a + c + b
\implies 0 + b = a + c + b \implies b = a + b + c \\
\implies b = 0 + c \implies b = c
$$
Since this looks easier than the one presented in the video, is this demo right or is there something I'm missing?
The only thing I noticed is that in the first step (adding $b$ to both sides) I'm using the fact that $=$ is a relation of equivalence, but if one didn't want to use this fact I don't know how are you proving this without an equivalence relation. Also, I'm using that $+$ is an additive operation and thus using the definition of additive operations that grants the commutative rule applys.

Do you know if the youtuber was trying to construct Z from the ground up or were they just trying to prove this one thing. If it is a construction, he might have proven that Z under addition is commutative later on.

@MusicalTaco Wasn't specified in the video but that's a really good reason, the odd thing though is that he first did a video of the axioms of Z where he stated that the commutative property of the integers was an axiom https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lqSS4_6pLL0&list=PLu3jV67N5CiSZ5MuGJQei6Q4U9m1zVQNZ&index=1 and he wrote that this was the second axiom and association was the third one (also by calling them axioms hes already stating that no prove is needed)

Some people make videos about rather trivial things , not really new. I over and over again wonder about the feedback.

If you are working in a structure that assumes commutativity as an axiom, then your proof is fine. You just found another way to prove the same statement. Otherwise, there are structures that do not assume commutativity and in such a case noticing how you can still recover the same property using another axiom is meaningful in developing the theory.
